# SUBTRACTION between two SUM of rows in one table in one query

Tags: sql, sum, subtraction

I need to show in one table result the SUM of all amount WHERE  description= Add Value; SUM all amount WHERE description= Game Credit Used; SUBTRACTION Between SUM Add Value - Game Credit Used. = all this actions only in one table FROM member_transactions WHERE member = ' 32-185149  ';

I tried to write this queries: (SQL that isn't working)

## test

```
SELECT member, description, SUM(amount)  
  FROM member_transactions  
 WHERE member = '32-185149' AND description = 'Add Value'  
UNION  
SELECT member, description,SUM(amount) AS GameCreditUsed  
  FROM member_transactions  
 WHERE member = '32-185149' AND description = 'Game Credit Used';
```

## need to join  SUBTRACTION

```
SELECT ((SELECT SUM(amount) FROM member_transactions WHERE member = '32-185149' AND description = 'Add Value')  
      - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM member_transactions WHERE member = '32-185149' AND description = 'Game Credit Used')) 
    AS Balance;
```

I need to see like this table:

```
member         description       Result  
32-185149      Add Value         240  
32-185149      Game Credit Used   40  
                                 200
```

And I need one query for all actions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT member, description,
       SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'Add Value' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as add_value,
       SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'Game Credit Used' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as game_credit_used,
FROM member_transactions
WHERE member = '32-185149' ;
```

You can just subtract the values rather than putting them in separate columns in you want the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT member, description, SUM(amount)  
  FROM member_transactions  
 WHERE member = '32-185149' AND description IN ('Add Value', 'Game Credit Used')  
 GROUP BY member, description
```

The total at the end should be on the application but if you really want it need to do UNION

```
SELECT member, description, SUM(amount)  
  FROM member_transactions  
 WHERE member = '32-185149' AND description IN ('Add Value', 'Game Credit Used')  
 GROUP BY member, description
UNION 
SELECT '' as member, 
       'total' as description, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN description = 'Add Value' THEN amount 
                WHEN description = 'Game Credit Used' THEN -amount 
                ELSE 0 
           END
          )  as total
  FROM member_transactions  
 WHERE member = '32-185149' 
 GROUP BY member
```